# El Capitan Finder shows 10 GB more disk space

Tags: macos, disk-space

I'm running 10.11.2 on a MBP 15". Since a few weeks ago I am observing a strange phenomenon: all disks show roughly 10GB more free space than they really have.

E.g. I plug a USB drive in that has 32 GB. Finder shows me 42 GB.

Other example: Finder shows that I have 11GB free. I pull a 2 GB file to the Finder and get the message: not enough disk space.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

I tried out the usual Apple voodoo things (PRAM reset etc), and one behaved strange: when I started the Macbook with pressed Shift-key (safe start), it took very, very long. Usually this takes like 5 minutes, this time it took more than 40 Minutes (huh!).

After that I just restarted again and everything was fine. So it looks like safe start fixed the problem

Comment: This sounds like the volume data structures were damaged. Safe boot does a volume repair (among other things). I'd recommend starting in [Recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314), and running Disk Utility's First Aid on the disk. It's equivalent to what Safe book does, but Disk Utility will tell you what it found/fixed. Hopefully it'll just tell you everything's ok (now), but just in case...

Comment: @GordonDavisson: the strange thing was, that the wrong size was showed on _all_ connected disks, not just the internal one. Thanks for your input :-)

Answer (score -2):

Probably a corruption in one of the system caches (that are emptied when starting in Safe Mode).